# Что такое кренедец? Почему не гуглится?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, жаргон

Что ли это съединенье крантов и... песеца? в смысле полного абзаца?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как образовано слово "кренедец"? Лексическое значение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При поиске - "кренедец" - выдается только пять позиций, шестая - наш сайт.  Возможно, какая-то описка?
Есть очень *похожее словечко* - **"крендец"**, используется напропалую:

*Крендец морским перевозкам = крендец глобализации = счастье мировое.*
*Директор АвтоВАЗа становится руководителем ракетно-космической промышленности России. Всё! Крендец нашему космосу!*
*Предуведомление. Предлагаемый рассказ относится к условному циклу «Солдатские рассказы времён, когда пришёл крендец».*
*Крендец стране.Сегодня Якеменко покинул пост главы Росмолодежи. Но крендец стране наступит отнюдь не по этой причине.*

По смыслу - похоже на Ваше. Откуда взялось?.. Чего не знаю - того придумывать не буду.

Comment: Но я же заскриншотила примеры употребления... Трижды описка?

Comment: Да, я их видела - всего пять штук. Поэтому и возникла логичная мысль:  об описке или обычной ошибке. Попыталась поискать что-то очень похожее.

Comment: Автор отозвалась: опечатка таки.

Answer (score 1):

> Что такое *кренедец?*

Думаю, то же самое, что и [***крындец.***](http://teenslang.su/id/16576)

[**Словарь синонимов**.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/337069/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%86)

Comment: А откуда довесочное Е, у крындеца-то? И последний скуль взяуси?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova - судя по урле, крындец взялся из тинового сленга.. А лингву молодняка лучше никогда не анализировать в поисках логики и здравого смысла

Comment: Я редактирую текст: обязана понимать. И тут я не логики искала, а недоумевала, почему поиск ничего не выдаёт. Автор признался: опечатка.